# Как загрузить страницу в странице JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Привет всем! Нужно как-то реализовать подгрузку страницы по клику

Нажимаем и откуда-нибудь подгружается html страница (или ее часть), но мы остаемся там же, где и были.

Answer (score 1):

вариантов несколько, самый простой это iframe которому нужно указать некое имя, и ссылки  c аттрибутом target таким как name у iframe. Пример [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp).
И вариант посложнее, это уже с ajax, например с jquery  функция [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/).